# Pandas bar charts groups together

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pivot, bar-chart

I have a quite large csv file from a set of benchmarks, and would like to plot groups of results together in 3s. F.ex:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""benchmark,smt,speedup
   b1, smt1, 100
   b1, smt2, 111
   b1, smt4, 118
   b2, smt1, 100
   b2, smt2, 108
   b2, smt4, 109
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")

df.plot(kind="bar")
```

This gives me a bar-plot with every bar evenly spaced. But how can I make results from b1 grouped together without any spacing, then have a space before the the b2 is grouped together?

I.e. I get:

[image]

But want something like:

[image]

with evert 3 bars representing the speedup for smt1,smt2 and smt4 for each given benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hve some delimiter inconsistency but you can overcome it as me

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""benchmark;smt;speedup
   b1, smt1, 100
   b1, smt2, 111
   b1, smt4, 118
   b2, smt1, 100
   b2, smt2, 108
   b2, smt4, 109
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",", skiprows=1, names=['benchmark', 'smt', 'speedup'])

df.pivot(index='benchmark', columns='smt').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1st change your sep in columns name it should be `,` not `;`

```
TESTDATA = StringIO("""benchmark,smt,speedup
   b1, smt1, 100
   b1, smt2, 111
   b1, smt4, 118
   b2, smt1, 100
   b2, smt2, 108
   b2, smt4, 109
    """)
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")
```

Then we do `pivot` and `plot`

```
df.pivot(*df.columns)
Out[446]: 
smt         smt1   smt2   smt4
benchmark                     
   b1        100    111    118
   b2        100    108    109
df.pivot(*df.columns).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]